React Grid Layout - Want to make it both horizontal | vertical compactType
I am using react grid layout with my nextJs app. Issue i am facing is that i can either mention the compactType to be horizontal or vertical. This is causing some rearrangement of my divs inside the layout in a manner which is now what I want. I want them to clip to both directions and try to stack left to right, then top to bottom.
Any help is appreciated on how i can achieve this.
The code is generic ReactGridLayout code, with compactType either horizontal or vertical
